# jquery check background color issue

Tags: jquery, background-color

A very similar question has been asked before and I'm pretty new to this, but I have failed to notice an error in the following peace of code. Could you please let me know if there is anything wrong with it?

```
if ( $("#test").css("background-color") == "green" )
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: `.css` will return bg color like this `rgb(245, 180, 5)`, so will not be able to compare it with `green`

Comment: Great! Appreciate that!

Comment: I don't know your code, but maybe it would be better to check an attribute(for example "class") of your html-element rather than it's color ?

Comment: pxL, got it right. I wanted to check which button was highlighted based on their background color.

Answer (score 1):

[jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/css/) says:

> ...Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255)....

So you should maybe try something like this

```
if($("#test").css('background-color') == 'rgb(0, 128, 0)' || $("#test").css('background-color') == '#00800') {...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this:

$("#test").css( "background-color", "green" );
```